# How to read from JSON dynamic content into an object?

Tags: c#, .net, json

I need to define in a json file `bands` containing a dynamic value ranges configuration. They might change in future, so I would like it to look like this:

```
"Bands": {
    "5-15": [ 5000, 15000 ],
    "15-30": [ 15000, 30000 ],
    "30-45": [ 30000, 45000 ],
    "45-60": [ 45000, 60000 ],
    "60-100": [ 60000, 100000 ]
}
```

Is it possible to read with this json format and store it in an object?

I tried this:

```
public class BandsMapping
{
    public List<Bands> Bands { get; set; }
}

public class Bands
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<int> ValueRanges { get; set; }
}
```

But it fails because there's no `Name` neither `ValueRanges` in the json file. But I would like the json file to look something like this.

Any idea on how can I achieve that?

Comment: I suspect you can deserialize the JSON for `Bands` into a `Dictionary<string, int[]>` and then convert it to the mapping you want.

Comment: Exactly as you suspected :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Dictionary<string, List<int>>` or `Dictionary<string, int[]>` for `Bands` content instead of just `List<int>`

```cs
public class BandsMapping
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<int>> Bands { get; set; }
}
```

Dictionary key represents a `string` with range, dictionary value is an array or list of integer values. You can also easily convert the dictionary into list of `Bands` items using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) method

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BandsMapping>(jsonString);
var bandsList = result.Bands
    .Select(kvp => new Bands { Name = kvp.Key, ValueRanges = kvp.Value })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It wasn't me! And it did work :) Thanks ^^ They are also downvoting my question and don't understand the reason...

Comment: I swear I thougth this was an old post. Exact same type of dupe exact same comment.